# How to translate spoken transcript using google translation by Python

Tags: python, translation

I'm new to coding and Python so forgive my lack of using the proper vocabulary. I'm working on a leisurely project where I am trying to translate text from 'speech recognition code'. I've found a way to using the Python googletrans module to translate pre-typed words, but am curious if there is a way to translate the transcript from my mic as source using the same method, thanks!

Here is the 'speech recognition code' I am using.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
mic = sr.Microphone()
with mic as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    audio = r.listen(source)
    transcript = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print(transcript)
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you installed the speech_recognition module ? Is it a Python module or you had created it ?

Comment: @D.O. Yes! It's a Python module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In the example you have given there, you have created a variable, `transcript`, which contains a string which you should simply be able to pass to the `translate` function of googletrans `Translator` object. Unless either of these two modules are doing something very strange, this should work.

For example, if you wanted translate to German:

```
trans = googletrans.Translator()
trans.translate(transcript, dest='de')
```

(You'll also need to to `import googletrans` at the start).

Comment: Ah, got it! That's actually what I did on instinct so good to know I was originally on the track. Thank you!

Comment: @concretecowboy Great - glad it helped! You may want to mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question - just makes it easier for others to find.